# Google map api v3, how zoom in/out smoothly

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

my problem is zoom in/out behaviour. that is not very smooth like https://maps.google.com/ , here is the url of my map : http://store.elegantways.com/store-locator.html.

i am loading map in a div. can some figure out the issue ?

Comment: Please be more specific what you mean by "not very smooth", I tried using the map on your site and I don't feel like it is any less smooth than the one provided on Google Maps.

Comment: i mean that the mine map Tiles do not laod like the one on google site.

Comment: on google site, there comes a red color border while zoom in out. is there any api/service to do ?

Comment: I believe you may need to add that as a custom functionality.

Comment: Your map looks fine to me. Check your internet connection.

Comment: Hi Marcelo, yeah it looks fine, but zoom in/out is not like google default map. both are accessing from same connecton.